# Failed to start broadcast: kurento.MediaPipeline not found (Code:40101, Type:null, Data: {"type":"MEDIA_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND"})

Tags: java, ubuntu, ffmpeg, kurento, openmeetings

I am facing this issue when I opened any conference room or any meeting then the camera or microphone or sharedscreen is opened from just 1 or 2 seconds and then
 gone and error message popup in the image below which is attached and in text

**I am using open-meeting version 5.0.0-M3 WebRTC**

```
> Failed to start broadcast: Object
> '4f09d0d4-f52f-4731-9e54-124e2da0ca9a_kurento.MediaPipeline' not found
> (Code:40101, Type:null, Data: {"type":"MEDIA_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND"})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to set-up latest KMS (6.13.0 ATM)

And ensure only one instance of OpenMeetings is connected to this particular instance of KMS

Comment: okay, that would be great because after updating KMS to the latest then I would be worked. Thanks